# DragonBones/createJS onclick

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know how to make an armature clickable?  I've tried

`armature.onclick = doSomething;`
`armature.addEventListener(MouseEvent,MouseDown,doSomething);`
`armature.getDisplay().onclick = doSomething;`

`_body = armature.getBone("body");`
`_body.onclick = doSomething;`

but nothing works and I cannot find any documentation, and the examples on the DragonBones page only show canvas.onclick = doSomething; which works, but triggers function when you click anywhere on the canvas.

Thanks,
Sandra

Comment: If you attach a click handler to `canvas` it'll trigger whenever you click anywhere inside a canvas... if you want to perform an action upon clicking a particular area then you'll have perform calculations based on the mouse position...

Comment: Thanks - I'm trying to figure out if there's a workaround in order to access them directly - as in EaselJS where you can write hero.onClick = doThis;  but I would like to use DragonBones to create the sprite sheets... I'll post if I can figure it out...

Comment: You can't select a particular element in canvas (there are no *elements* in canvas as far as i know, it's like a board). If you want to access elements, look into svg...

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use like this

```
this.armature.getDisplay().addEventListener("click",
                                            function () { 
                                                          alert('working');  
                                                         }
                                             );
```